# What statistical analysis did they do in this paper?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

This is really a beginner question.  I have to perform a statistical analysis which is exactly the same as the one conducted in the table shown in the picture. Specifically, how to calcolate the positive/negative association within each type of bacteria, with the p-value? What method should I use? Is this a correlation? Is this a Fisher Exact Test? 
[image]

Comment: What part of the description in the paper are you having difficulty understanding? What are the terms the author(s) use(s) to describe the analysis?

Comment: Please provide a link to the full paper.

Comment: I don't understand how the p-value for the single group (bold numbers) have been calculated. The paper is "Population structure, virulence potential and antibiotic susceptibility of uropathogenic Escherichia coli from Northwest England", I don't think there is an open access version.

Comment: Paper is [here](http://jac.oxfordjournals.org/content/67/2/346.long) and is open access.

Answer (score 3):

The paper clearly states the following:

> Statistical analysis
>
> Unless otherwise stated, statistical analyses
>   were performed using Fisher's exact test with a threshold for
>   statistical significance of P < 0.05.

Comment: From my understanding of the Fisher's exact test, at the end we obtain ONE p-value. How to calculate the significance of the single group, as done by those authors (bold numbers)?

Comment: @Vaaal that's another question altogether, Prometheus' answer is correct.